# Struggling to generate a SOAP-Service based on wsdl file by using cxf

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

I am struggling to create a working SOAP-Service with Apache cxf from a wsdl-File. I am reaching the service, but got already the same Exception message as you see in the last code snippet. I show you some more code snippets because I'm new to that kind of creating webservices and do not know where my mistake is.
Thanks for your help!

Starting with my wsdl-File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="DataService" targetNamespace="http://service.data.com"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
              xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
              xmlns:test="http://service.data.com">

<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://service.data.com"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <element name="DataReq" type="test:DataReqType"/>
        <element name="DataRsp" type="test:DataRspType"/>

        <complexType name="DataReqType">
            <sequence>
                <element minOccurs="0" name="DataXML" nillable="true" type="test:DataXML"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="DataRspType">
            <sequence>
                <element name="DataError" type="test:DataError"/>
                <element name="success" nillable="true" type="int"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="DataXML">
            <sequence>
                <element name="xmlString" type="test:String200"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="DataError">
            <sequence>
                <element name="errorCode" nillable="false" type="int"/>
                <element name="errorMessage" nillable="true" type="test:String40"/>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <simpleType name="String40">
            <restriction base="string">
                <maxLength value="40"/>
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>
        <simpleType name="String200">
            <restriction base="string">
                <maxLength value="200"/>
            </restriction>
        </simpleType>

    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="PostDataReq">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="test:DataReq"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="PostDataRsp">
    <wsdl:part name="body" element="test:DataRsp"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="DataPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="dataImport">
        <wsdl:input message="test:PostDataReq"/>
        <wsdl:output message="test:PostDataRsp"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="DataSOAPBinding" type="test:DataPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="dataImport">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://service.data.com/dataImport"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="DataService">
    <wsdl:port binding="test:DataSOAPBinding" name="DataServicePort">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:32080/test/services/dataImport"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

My cxf-servlet.xml with bean for hosting the service:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
         http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

<jaxws:endpoint id="DataService"
                implementor="com.test.DataService"
                address="/dataImport">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

The result I got when requesting the service in browser added "?wsdl":

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:tns="http://service.data.com"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"
xmlns:ns1="http://data.server.test.com/" name="DataService"
targetNamespace="http://service.data.com">
<wsdl:import location="http://localhost:32080/dataImport?wsdl=DataService.wsdl"
 namespace="http://data.server.test.com/"> </wsdl:import>
 <wsdl:binding name="DataServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:DataService">
 <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="DataService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:DataServiceSoapBinding" name="DataServicePort">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:32080/dataImport"/>
    </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The Post-Request I'm doing with SOAP-UI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ser="http://service.data.com">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ser:DataReq>
        <ser:DataXML>
            <ser:xmlString>Test</ser:xmlString>
        </ser:DataXML>
    </ser:DataReq>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And it responses with the following Exception:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Message part {http://service.data.com}DataReq was not recognized.
            (Does it exist in service WSDL?)</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: So you are developing according to the WSDL-first approach as documented here http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-service.html? Can you please share your wsdl2java config or ideally a small runnable testproject to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by starting a new seperated project from the scratch. I did several mistakes in my code.

1) In cxf-servlet.xml I have to cal the generated **DataPortImpl** instead of the **DataService**:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="DataService"
                implementor="com.test.DataPortImpl"
                address="/dataImport">
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

2) Violation of some convetions in my wsdl-File which are required for usage of cxf:

Have to replace message-part-elements **DataReq** and **DataRsp** by **Data** for Request and **DataResponse** for Response.

3) The executing cxf-command was fine:

```
wsdl2java -server -impl  -d %pathToDirectory% -p %pathToPackage%
-wsdlLocation classpath:%relativePathToWSDL% %pathToWSDL%
```